# Unable to add resize event to tinymce editor

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce

I am not able to add  resize event to tinymce editor. it is giving me:-

```
Uncaught TypeError: tinymce.dom.Event.add is not a function
```

What is the right way to do so?

```
tinymce.init({
        selector: ".tinymceTextarea",
        width:      '100%',
        height:     '100%',
        plugins:    plugins,
        statusbar:  false,
        menubar:    false,
        toolbar:    toolbar,
        fontsize_formats : "8px 10px 12px 14px 16px 18px 20px 24px 32px 36px",
    //    init_instance_callback: "initTinyMCE",
        setup: function(e) {
        e.on('init', function() { 
            tinymce.dom.Event.add(e.getWin(), "resize", function(e1) {
                console.log("=====")
            })
        });

});
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: do  you want to  trigger the event on tinymice editor resize !

Comment: yes. actually I want to add resize event to dom?

Comment: Ok. check my answer which is chaining in a line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the below snippet without chaining

```
$("#your_textarea_id").tinymce().getWin().bind('resize',function() {
    console.log('resize triggered !');

    // Your Code goes here.
});
```

Comment: plus 1, as this is also a valid solution

Answer (score 2):

This can easiliy be achieved using the setup tinymce configuration parameter `setup` to add a window resize handler:

```
setup: function(ed){
    ed.on('init', function() { 
        $(ed.getWin()).bind('resize', function(e){
            console.log('Editor window resized!');
        })
    });
}
```

See my tinymce fiddle here: http://fiddle.tinymce.com/snfaab